# Can a map which strictly decrease distances preserve lengths of paths?

Tags: metric-spaces, curves, lipschitz-functions, metric-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be length spaces, and suppose $f:X \to Y$ satisfies $$ (*) \, \, d^Y(f(x),f(y))<d^X(x,y)$$ for all $x,y \in X, x \neq y$.

**Question:** Is it possible that $f$ preserves lengths of paths?

**Remark:** Since  length preserving is a local property, we can also localize the condition $(*)$, requiring it to only hold locally around every point of $X$.

(I am mainly interested in the smooth Riemannian case- when $X,Y$ are Riemannian manifolds, but then I do **not** assume $f$ is smooth or even $C^1$).

If there is such an $f$ (which preserves lengths), then it must **not** be a local homeomorphism. (Since [an arcwise isometry that is a local homeomorphism is a local isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018846/is-it-true-that-arcwise-isometry-that-is-also-a-local-homeomorphism-is-a-local-i)).

Of course, if $f$ was $k$-Lipschitz for $k<1$ the answer would be negative.

Comment: How are you defining the length of a path ?

Comment: @TomCollinge See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Length_of_a_curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

- $X = (0,2\pi)$
- $Y = \mathbb{R}^2$
- $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$